# I get this error in Symfony 2.3.17 even I clear cache manually or using console, hope some knows what really going on.. [P.S.I use Linux for OS]

Tags: php, symfony

I get this error in Symfony 2.3.17 even I clear cache manually or using console, hope some knows what really going on.. [P.S.I use Linux for OS]

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable: task in `/var/www/Symfony/src/Asanka/LoginBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 16`


Symfony/src/Asanka/LoginBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

<?php

namespace Asanka\LoginBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('AsankaLoginBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }

    public function loginAction()
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()->add('title', 'text')->add('body', 'textarea')->getForm();
        return $this->render('AsankaLoginBundle:Default:login.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));      
    }
}
```

Comment: post your `LoginBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php` code

Comment: I use task variable initially then later I changed in to the above code now it always trigger for task variable

Comment: Please dont post code in comments, just edit your answer.

Comment: @asalanka: that's a crucial information, please add it do your question. and come up with a proper title (shorten it). have you *verified* that you're editing the right file?